# ef core 2 - code first - access to view

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm working on asp.net core project and using ef core 2.0 as orm in a code-first pattern.There are 2 views that we need to access. The following workaround does the job but is very nasty.

create poco's representing the structure of the views
have migrations do it's thing
update-database
in the db rename the created tables (add an _tbl to the name)
create the views

now one can access the view because we tricked ef in believing they are actually tables.

This has major draw-backs :
- maintenance : every time the view is altered you need to go through the following procedure 1. drop view 2. remove _tbl from fake tablename 3. alter poco 4. add migration 5. update database 6. add _tbl to fake table name 7. create view
-usabillity : you can't have any navigation properties because there are no fk that can be used, so .include does not work

any suggestions on a better approach ?

Comment: Does mapping to the view do what you need: modelBuilder.Entity<PocoOfView>().ToTable("vw_YourView").HasKey(x => x.Id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice solution that is working was found in this blog:

http://laboremus.ug/?p=1708